# Mat Tab Group with RouterLink

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, angular-material, frontend

I am using a Mat Tab Group where I have two tabs, each with router links. Everything works fine with routing and view change but the problem what I am facing is once I click on the second tab, it's active state and ink bar doesn't get applied and still stays at the first tab. Below is my code:

```
<mat-tab-group routerTabs [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" [@.disabled]="true" [disableRipple]="true">
    <mat-tab>
        <div [routerLink]="['./home']" skipLocationChange>
             <span>Tab 1</span>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
        <div [routerLink]="['./about']" skipLocationChange>
             <span>Tab 2</span>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Have you checked material example for tabs with routing:https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-nav-bar-basic?

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it using Tab Group only. Is there any way?

Comment: can you create stackblitz?